# Why test routing policy do not match in vMX?

Tags: juniper

This is my routing-policy:

```
policy-statement rp-add-as-path-3times-local-as {
    term prefix1 {
        from {
            route-filter 1.1.1.0/22 orlonger;
        }
        then {
            as-path-expand "64500 64500 64500";
        }
    }
}
```

when I test it:

```
[edit]
root@vMX# run test policy rp-add-as-path-3times-local-as 1.1.1.0/23      

Policy rp-add-as-path-3times-local-as: 0 prefix accepted, 0 prefix rejected
```

you see there display:`0 prefix accepted, 0 prefix rejected`, why it do not match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The route you're testing against is not in the routing table.  Here's an example using your exact policy:

```
jhead@R1> show route 1.1.1.1/32

inet.0: 14 destinations, 14 routes (14 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

1.1.1.1/32         *[Local/0] 6d 20:17:36
                      Local via ge-0/0/0.0

jhead@R1> test policy rp-add-as-path-3times-local-as 1.1.1.1/32

inet.0: 14 destinations, 14 routes (14 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

1.1.1.1/32         *[Local/0] 6d 20:18:00
                      Local via ge-0/0/0.0

Policy rp-add-as-path-3times-local-as: 1 prefix accepted, 0 prefix rejected
```

If we try the same thing on a route that doesn't exist, we see no matches.

```
jhead@R1> show route 1.1.1.2/32

jhead@R1>

jhead@R1> test policy rp-add-as-path-3times-local-as 1.1.1.2/32

Policy rp-add-as-path-3times-local-as: 0 prefix accepted, 0 prefix rejected

jhead@R1>
```